# My Gparted does not work propperly

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted

[Please be nice to me - I'm not an expert in Linux]

You can see the errorlog provided by GParted here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/8o43b37c7fue1f9/gparted_details.htm

[image]

Hi Askubuntu. I am trying to resize my Asus Zenbook UX31E's partition, but it does not work using GParted on a LiveUSB. Here is what I do:

1. Download Ubtuntu 13.04, and burn it to a usb, using the software that comes with Ubuntu
2. Reboot into the Live envirorment
3. Unmount all the partitions
4. Open GParted
5. Resizes /dev/sda2 using "Right click -> Move/Resize". I have non-allocated space 98.01 GB, that I will give to my /dev/sda2/
6. Click the green checkmark (Apply all operations)
7. Click OK to the warning
8. And a error (With no futer information than that) comes up.
9. Click "Save details" (http://www.mediafire.com/download/8o43b37c7fue1f9/gparted_details.htm)
10. Ask you what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't use mediafire to post simple text output. It's an obnoxious service and I couldn't figure out how to get to the GParted details file you posted there through all the ads it plastered on my screen. Something like the [Ubuntu pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) works better and is free.

As to your problem, the usual cause is that GParted is trying to round a partition start or end point to the nearest 1MiB boundary (or possibly to some other value, depending on the alignment settings you've chosen), but your disk was originally partitioned with some other alignment scheme. This can cause GParted to mistakenly adjust the partition start or end point so that it overlaps with another partition, which of course is not legal.

The best solution is to adjust the start and/or end point of the partition so that there's a gap between it and the surrounding partitions. A 1MiB gap should be sufficient, but if that doesn't work, try 2MiB or even more.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have encountered the following bug: 
[Bug 686668 - Growing logical partition overlaps end of extended partition](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686668)

This bug was not fixed until GParted 0.14.1.  The workaround suggested by Rod should work.

I suggest you try using the latest version of GParted (currently 0.16.1).  The easiest way to do this is with [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) written to CD or USB flash drive.